# CentOS 6 to RHEL 8: Migrate to New Hardware then Upgrade OS -OR- Upgrade OS then Migrate to New Hardware

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, migration, upgrade

I have to migrate five physical servers (Dell R510) to new physical hardware (Dell R440) and, also, upgrade them from CentOS 6.2 to the latest RHEL OS. Which is the best route?

1. Migrate the servers to the new hardware then upgrade the OS?
2. Upgrade the OS then migrate to the new hardware?
3. Why?

Also, any suggestions on the most reliable method to migrate to the new hardware would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

Install the new OS in the new hardware, and then migrate your workload.